# unable to switch camera (front to rear) in react application using QrReader

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs

**This is the sample demonstration of what I'm intended to do. If anyone has any idea about this fix to make it work or any new logic please do share..**

This demo is implemented by using QrReader which I intend to use the camera which is on the devices and depending on what the user selects the camera which is used to read the QR is updated. I show the code just below. With all my regards, thank you in advance.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { QrReader } from 'react-qr-reader';
import './estilos.css';
  
function Lector() { 
  const [qrCodeData, setQrCodeData] = useState(null);
  const [activate, setActivate] = useState(false);
  const [facingMode, setFacingMode] = useState('environment');
  const qrReaderRef = useRef(null);
  const [cameras, setCameras] = useState([]);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices) => {
      const videoDevices = devices.filter((device) => device.kind === 'videoinput');
      setCameras(videoDevices);
    });
  }, []);
 
  const handleQRCodeScan = (data) => {
    if (data) {
      setQrCodeData(data);
      setActivate(true);
    }
  };

  const ventana = () => {
    window.open(qrCodeData);
  };

  const ventana2 = () => {
    window.open('https://qr.primerosauxilios.online/', '_top');
  };

  const handleCameraChange = (event) => {
    setFacingMode(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <article className="card">
      <button onClick={ventana2} style={{ cursor: 'pointer', background: 'orange' }}>
        Generar QR
      </button>

      <select name="select" onChange={handleCameraChange}>
        {cameras.map((camera) => (
          <option key={camera.deviceId} value={camera.deviceId}>
            {camera.label || `Camera ${camera.deviceId}`}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <div className="qr-box" style={{ background: 'black', position: 'relative' }}>
        <div style={{ width: '300px', height: '300px' }}>
          <QrReader
            ref={qrReaderRef}
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
            onResult={(result, error) => {
              if (result) {
                handleQRCodeScan(result.text);
              }

              if (error) {
                console.info(error);
              }
            }}
            facingMode={facingMode}
          />
          <div
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              top: '50%',
              left: '50%',
              transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
              border: '3px solid blue',
              width: '200px',
              height: '200px',
            }}
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Resultado del QR: {qrCodeData}</p>

      {activate ? (
        <button
          onClick={ventana}
          style={{ cursor: 'pointer', background: 'black', color: 'white' }}
        >
          Abrir
        </button>
      ) : (
        <button disabled style={{ background: 'red', color: 'white' }}>
          Esperando Link
        </button>
      )}
    </article>
  );
}

export default Lector;
```

Comment: Perhaps choosing front or rear is a system setting on the device.

Comment: Agreed, I'd imagine it's up to the user which camera they want to use. Plus, not all devices have multiple cameras